# Computing the vector field in the spherical coordinates

Tags: vector-fields

I need to compute the vector field which is given in spherical coordinates. As the unit vectors are dependent on the position I cannot integrate it right off the bat. I have

$$T(\theta,\phi)(\hat{\theta}+\hat{\phi}) sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$$
for $0<\theta<\pi$ and $0<\phi<2\pi$.

Do I just replace the unit vectors with their corresponding cartesian coordinate unit vectors and integrate?

Comment: The question is poorly worded. I am not sure what you want to do. Are you interested in writing a vector field in rectangular coordinates or are you trying to integrate a surface integral?

Comment: Integral surface integral

Comment: What kind of surface? Is it a sphere of radius one? Do you want to compute the flow in the direction normal to the surface? What is $T(\theta, \phi)$, is  it your parameterization? Have you drawn a picture of the situation? Can you show us?